# ESP32 + SD card- SD card get formatted automatically at random

Tags: c, esp32, sd-card

I am using ESP32 with an SD card, which is preloaded with some data. I read a file line by line for the functioning of the application. It works fine most of the time, but around 1 out of 10 time, the card gets formatted and I have to reload all the data into the SD card.

​

I am using the following library,

```
#include "FS.h"  
#include "SD.h"  
#include "SPI.h"
```

I tried to learn the pattern of this issue by trying various combination of restart, abrupt power off etc. But couldn't establish any connection.

I read each line very frequently ~ 100 times per second, I believe this may be the issue.

Comment: If it is working, but some of the times ... that points to SPI command issues which may be directly related to the SD card being used. Some SD cards can communicate over SPI at a faster rate than others. That means that you may have to adjust the SPI rate slower for cards that have problems. From what you describe, it seems all is good until there is a timing issue and then a garbled command is interpreted as a format or wipe of the SD. While you provide no [MRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'd start by lowering the SPI rate and see if it corrects the issue.